# LinearLayout setOnClickListener does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

As a beginner, I am trying to set the click event for the LinearLayout which is ListView's parent layout.It seems to ListView intercept LinearLayout event.

Here is my main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:clickable="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use this code and it does not work.

```
findViewById(R.id.ll).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "click");
        }
    });
```

Comment: linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.EmailTextView);
linearLayout.setOnClickLister(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "click");
        }
    });

Comment: @AkshayShinde, this won't work since it does not change anything. It does not matter if you cast your view to layout, or not.

Comment: try to setVisibility(GONE) to list view. then give some height to linearlayout. then give a try.

Comment: use this for LinearLayout `android:descendantFocusability(blocksDescendants);`

Comment: Try to remove weight and set your listview width and height to match_parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're right, `ListView` handles the click. You have two options.

1. Create a subclass of `LinearLayout`, listen for touch events, and whenever needed intercept them.
2. Instead of `LinearLayout` use `FrameLayout` and declare a view with height/width `match_parent` after `ListView`, and set click listener on that view.

   ```
   <FrameLayout>
       <ListView />
       <View 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: One more, when I use your second methods I find the ListView in FrameLayout does not work normal. How to make it work properly?

Answer (score -2):

Because you have ListView over it. ListView is getting the click.
If you want to click listView item then use

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener
```